# How to do a calculation based off a T/F condition in a Pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas

So I am really not sure how I should go about this. I am working with pandas in python. I have a csv file I converted into a data frame called `df`. I have this column:

```
Is_High_School
FALSE
FALSE
FALSE
TRUE
FALSE
...
```

And I have another column:

```
Student_Count
454
343
213
223
676
...
```

I want to calculate the mean and stdev of the student count, but only where `Is_High_School` is FALSE.

May I get some direction with how to approach this? I have tried the `df.where()`, and it isn't working for me because I get NaN, and I don't know how to propagate that so that I can calculate in another column only where that condition is met. Thanks, I really appreciate it.

edit:

I created a smaller dataframe called hs. Here it is:

```
dataframe:   Is_High_School  Student_Count_Total
0             False                  415
1             False                  241
2             False                  346
3             False                   91
4             False                  248
..              ...                  ...
655           False                  509
656           False                  507
657            True                  341
658            True                 1086
659            True                 1308
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just filter your dataframe according to the condition is required then calculate it.

```
filtered_df=df.loc[df['Is_High_School'] ==False]

mean_val=filtered_df['Student_Count'].mean()

std_dev=filtered_df['Student_Count'].std()
```

Comment: I also keep getting empty dataframe for this as well. I am not really sure why.

Comment: Post your full dataframe

Comment: @taylor my guess is the column values of "FALSE" and "TRUE" isn't exactly that. Maybe there's some whitespace you did not notice

Comment: Maybe? I believe it is recognized as a boolean value even though the csv just has them typed "FALSE" and "TRUE", but I am not sure if that changes anything? I am a novice at this, and I really appreciate the help.

Comment: yeah it is a boolean value based on the dataframe you posted. Change ```"FALSE"``` to ```False```

Answer (score 0):

If you want do want have a dataframe with only no high school you can do this:

```
df = df[df['Is_High_School'] == False]
```

But but don't see the reason for that. You can just do:

```
mean_series = df.groupby(['Is_High_School']).mean()
std_series = df.groupby(['Is_High_School']).std()
```

So you get mean and std for the student count. Your output should then look something like that (concrete values from this ouput are just dummies):

```
Is_Highschool  Student_Count              
False          758.000000
True           773.166667
```

Comment: Would there be a reason why I keep getting empty dataframe?

Comment: I think you have to post your data. At best a minimal example dataframe with the same issue. So we can reproduce the problem. Otherwise it would be just guessing out of nowhere.

Comment: I added it. I appreciate the help a ton

Comment: @mightyandweakcoder ist right. It's a boolean value not a string. I edited my answer.